# Start JavaFX application on new JVM via code

Tags: exception, javafx, jvm, launch

I'm trying to get my JavaFX Application to launch other Classes through a button click using this code:

`btn.setOnAction(click -> {ClientMain.main(new String[]{});});`

However this generates the following exception:

`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once`

The class I'm trying to launch, ClientMain, extends Application, and I've managed to get an instance of it running by simply calling its start() method.

However, I need the application to run on a separate JVM than the caller's. How could I solve this?

Let me know if details are needed.

Comment: [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)